# Downloading wikipedia data from specific url

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia

I want to download data from [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_districts_of_Germany)
I am a rookie at this and can'T find any relevant articles. Most of them are on downloading full Wikipedia. I need just one specific URL data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy/paste into spreadsheet tool? If you are doing it once, why get any more complicated?

http://pastebin.com/raw/bKAFbReV

---

Or, https://www.google.ch/search?q=wikipedia+table+to+csv

Comment: Than ou so much :)